# Insertion points for dynamic loading of polymer element

Tags: polymer

How to use insertion points for dynamic loading of polymer element. I want to load child polymer element based on the type which I get in parent polymer element.

```
<polmer-element name="child-one" attributes="data">
    <template>
        {{data.name}}, {{data.age}}
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer("child-one", {
        })
    <script>
</polmer-element>

<polmer-element name="child-two" attributes="data">
    <template>
        {{data.location}}
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer("child-two", {
        })
    <script>
</polmer-element>

<polmer-element name="parent-element" attributes="dataList type">
    <template>
        <template repeat="data in dataList">
            //Here based on type, I want to load child-one or child-two. Ideally the number of childs will increase.
            //I need to send the data also along with that.
            //So it might be <child-one data="{{data}}"></child-one> or <child-two data="{{data}}"></child-two>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer("parent-element", {
        })
    <script>
</polmer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
<polymer-element id="child-one" name="child-one" attributes="data" noscript>
    <template>
       {{data.name}}, {{data.age}}
    </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="child-two" attributes="data" noscript>
    <template>
        {{data.location}}
    </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="parent-element" attributes="dataList type">
    <template>
      <template id="one">
        <child-one data="{{data}}"></child-one>
        </template>      
      <template id="two">
        <child-two data="{{data}}"></child-two>
        </template>      
        <template repeat="{{data in dataList}}">
          <template bind ref="{{type}}"></template>
        </template>
    </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('parent-element', {
      dataList: [{name:'a',age:1, location:'q'},{name:'b',age:2, location:'qq'},{name:'c',age:3, location:'qqq'},{name:'d',age:4, location:'qqqq'}]
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<parent-element type="two">

</parent-element>
```

Comment: I think template ref brings in a template by id. I want to bring in a polymer element itself. for template ref, we need to have a template and that template id is mentioned in the ref to bring it.

Comment: You can use nested templates with if condition, but i don't like it.

Comment: Yeah. I am using the same for the moment. but would like to change it.